# Qual exatamente a função da classe IdentityModels em C# e como funciona o ApplicationDbContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Desenvolvi uma aplicação em C# onde possuo a classe IdentityModels, onde a partir dela criei uma lista das minhas classes baseadas no ApplicationDbContext. Utilizei as migrations para criação das tabelas no banco a partir dessas classes, mas queria entender o conceito técnico da utilização do IdentityModels e do ApplicationDbContext.

Meu código na Classe IdentityModels

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Company> Companies { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Category> Categories{ get; set; }

    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
```